# Is it possible to handle QGis server requests through nodejs

Tags: qgis-server, node-js

I have a nodejs based application server. I would also like to add qgis-server functionality to node. Something like this:

```
expressapp.get(someAuthenticationMiddleware(), qgisServerRequestHandler());
```

I can't find any reference on how to call/use fast-cgi script through nodejs. Has anyone done it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js cannot run and forward requests to a fast cgi application. Solution for the way i want to use qgis-server is, to use the default installation of qgis-server via apache2 and lib-mod-fcgid, then using a reverse proxy technique for forwarding requests to apache.